# How can I get the keybindings in a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to be able to look up all the existing keybindings from within a Visual Studio Code extension.

There are some hacky ways involving guessing the user data path and reading the `keybindings.json` file, but VS Code allows for the user data path to be passed in as an argument so this won't always be accurate.

There is [this file](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/platform/environment/node/environmentService.ts) in the source code of VS Code which has a `appKeybindingsPath` property, but I don't think I can access this from within the context of an extension.

Is it possible to get the keybindings somehow?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102692/can-i-see-and-individually-disable-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-sublime-text-keym/61526583#61526583 for a way to filter `user`-defined shortcuts that may be in v1.45.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on an extension within vscode and click on the "Contributions" tab near the top, you can see all of the settings and commands that are exposed by that extension.

I have not written my own extension so I do not know if this information is auto-generated or the developer needs to write it. So it is possible some extensions are more thorough than others.