# Can I see, and individually disable, keyboard shortcuts for extensions, such as the Sublime Text Keymap extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I started using VS Code, I installed the "Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer" extension, to make it act more like Sublime, because that is what I was familiar with.

Now, I would like to use the default shortcuts. I want to switch gradually, maybe by disabling a few Sublime shortcuts at a time, or by at least knowing which shortcuts are coming from the Sublime extension, so I can train myself to stop using them.

**Is there any easy way to see which shortcuts are coming from the Sublime extension, and ideally disable some, but not all, of them?**

If I look at the "Keyboard Shortcuts" list, it shows the default shortcuts and the Sublime shortcuts mixed together, with no hint as to which is which, as far as I can tell. Example:
[image: VSCode quickOpen shortcuts]

It shows both Command+P and Command+T as shortcuts for `workbench.action.quickOpen`, both with a source of "Default". But I know that Command+T is coming from the extension, because if I disable the extension, I don't see it (but I still see Command+P). Disabling the extension and restarting VS Code is kind of inconvenient, so I would like an easy way to see which shortcuts are coming from the extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can see a comprehensive list of all keybindings the extension includes in the "Contributions" tab of the extension itself:

[image]

I'm not aware of any options to display this in the keyboard shortcuts UI directly. However, you could put the two tabs side-by-side for easy comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated and better method to filter the `Keyboard Shortcuts` editor to show which keybindings are contributed by a specific extension.  See [Specify which extension provides a specific keyboard shortcut](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/121673).  And here is an example where I search for one of my extensions, `Toggle Line Comments` to see if it contributes any keybindings.

And then it would be easy to disable or re-bind any of those keybindings.

[image: showExtension keybindings]

Also you can click on the Extension gear icon in the Extensions list.  That will bring up a menu with an `Extension Keyboard Shortcuts` option.  Which will open the Keyboard Shortcuts editor with a search already completed for any keybindings contributed by that extension.

[image: keybindings by extension]

---

Keep an eye on this PR https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/95713 (Show keybinding source in GUI).  Looks like it may be included in vscode v1.45.  It would allow you to filter the "Keyboard Shortcuts" by user-defined or extension.  From the above link:

> **Filters examples:**
>
> `@user` - shows user defined keybindings
>
> `@default` - shows default keybindings
>
> `@extensions` - shows all extension contributed keybindings
>
> `@extensions:"${EXTENSION_NAME}"` - shows keybindings contributed by
> ${EXTENSION_NAME}
>
> `@extensions:${EXTENSION_NAME}` - same as above only without quotes
> (spaces are invalid for this one)

> Searching with filter and text also works:
>
> `@extensions:bookmarks list` - shows keybindings from bookmarks
> extension that contain the word "list"

---

And then with such a filtered list it would be easy to disable whichever commands you wished.